# Subscribing to Angular 6 POST request

Tags: spring-boot, angular6

### Scenario

I have an Angular 6 front end that communicates with a Spring Boot back end. The back end uses PostgreSQL as a database. The thing I want to do is to send a username to the data base and then return his email and print it on a page using Angular 6. 
But, I am struggling with the Angular POST request where on subscribing to it I get a JSON parsing error in Chrome developer tools.

### Code

**Spring Boot**

This works fine as I have tested it by printing the email returned from the database on the console.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetMail(@RequestBody String username) {
    try{
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        //System.out.println(user.getEmail()); Testing purpose
        return user.getEmail();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace(); Prints out NullException StackTrace.
        return "Not Present";
    }
}
```

**Angular 6**

In the following code, I think the problem is in the subscription method as I am getting a JSON parsing error in Chrome developer tools.

```
httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})};

reset(username:string) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/reset', username, this.httpOptions).subscribe(data=> {
        this.email = data as any;
    });
}
console.log(this.email) // Prints undefined
```

### Error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8090/reset", ok: false, …}
    >error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "abcdefg@yahoo.com"}
    >headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
    message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8090/reset"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "http://localhost:8090/reset"
```

Comment: Did you try in your subscription response => response.text()

Comment: It doesn't work C.Weber. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to serialize a string to JSON. If your controller would return an object the `@RestController` annotation would serialize it properly. In case you want to return just a string you have to return `JSONObject.quote(user.getEmail())`; You can get the JSONObject dependency from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
But I encourage you to always return objects as a response from your rest controllers.

Comment: Isn't `String` supposed to be an object in Java ? If, yes then, am I not returning an Object. I'm getting confused and also I am using `@RestCotroller`

Comment: Yes every `String` is an object in Java that's correct. But it is a complex, non ordinary one. You can read about it here: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html
By returning an object I meant a a POJO: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html  
Hope it helps!